# MongoDB instance not inserting data

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I don't have MongoDB installed on my system, an instance is created virtually to the before mentioned IP address.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://....../')

mydb = client.test_database

import datetime

myrecord = {
        "author": "Duke",
        "title" : "PyMongo 101",
        "tags" : ["MongoDB", "PyMongo", "Tutorial"],
        "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

record_id = mydb.mytable.insert_one(myrecord)

print (record_id)
print (mydb.collection_names())
```

[This the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbkLB.png)

Answer (score 0):

The MongoClient does not connect immediately. It is a "lazy" connection. Which means it doesn't attempt to connect until you run the `insert` method. The specific error you are receiving indicates that the driver was unable to connect to `5.9.84.39:5555`.

You need to ensure the client can connect to the server. You should check the following items on both the machine running the Python code and the server running MongoDB.

- Firewalls
- Whitelists
- Connectivity with the Mongo Shell